# Eventual garbage screen on Commodore PET 2001N

Tags: display, commodore-pet

I have a Commodore PET 2001N 32K that boots and runs fine but eventually (sometimes minutes, sometimes hours) it goes to a garbage screen, and it will stay that way if I immediately cycle the power. After it cools down it will work again.

Are RAM/ROM chips or capacitors more likely to be at fault in this case?

Comment: It could also be a solder point, a wire on the PCB, anything. Such temperature dependent errors are hard to find. You might need to use an oscilloscope to analyse deeper by checking what is still running, and prepare for multiple hours of frustration. :-}

Comment: Coolant spray is the way to go here. Let the computer warm up until the condition is there, then spray selective suspected components until it goes away. The part you sprayed last is probably the culprit. Check this part (and its vicinity), and its solder connections.

Comment: Coolant spray is a great idea, thanks. Fortunately this is not my daily driver :)

Comment: @RedFilter I'd be impressed if you were posting on this site with a PET 2001.